# while loop in Java not working as I wanted

Tags: java, while-loop

I wanted to write a program which will take user input, as long as the input is not 0 it will keep on asking for input.

**How I did it:** I decided to check if the 1st input is 0 or not, if it is 0 then the program will exit right away. If the first input is not 0 then it will ask user to input more numbers.

**My problem**: It asks me only 2 times and then executes the  Program end statement.

**My Code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MyArList {

private static final int num2 = 0;

public static void main (String[] args){


    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
    int num1 = userInput.nextInt(); 

    if (num1==0){
        System.out.println("program exits");
    }
    else
    {System.out.print("Enter more numbers: ");



    while(!(userInput.nextInt()==0))


        System.out.print("Progam ends ");


    }

}
}
```

I also thought of/ tried do while but that did not work either

```
if( num1==0){

            System.out.println("Program exits");

    }
    else{

        do{
            System.out.print("Enter more numbers: ");
        int num2 = userInput2.nextInt(); 
        }while(!(num2==0));
```

Thank You for your valuable time and comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program is working well.  It will let you keep typing numbers until you type `0`.  It's just that you will keep seeing "Program ends" until you type `0`.  Your output statement is confusing yourself.

Inside your `while` loop, print `"Keep entering more numbers"` instead of `"Program ends "`.  Print `"Program ends"` after the `while` loop completes.

Answer (score -1):

I took your first approach and just changed the while loop, so you could better say, what u did wrong. 
Take a look:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyArList {

    private static final int num2 = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter 1st number: ");
        int num1 = userInput.nextInt();

        if (num1 == 0) {
            System.out.println("program exits");
        } else {
            do
                System.out.print("Enter more numbers: ");
            while (!(userInput.nextInt() == 0));
            System.out.print("Progam ends ");
        }
    }
}
```